# Que signifie 'Faire le tarba'?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, verlan

Que signifie *Faire le tarba*?

J'ai recherché sur Google et trouvé que *tarba* est du verlan pour *bâtard*. Je comprends ce mot, mais je ne vois pas ce que signifie l'expression.

Comment: Mal se comporter.

Comment: J'connaissais pas l'utilisation du verlan pour ce mot. Il s'agit sinon de mal se comporter (ce qui est assez vaste), d'agir de manière égoïste (si tu veux pas partager ton gâteau, etc.), avec potentiellement un p'tit goût de rancune de la part du locuteur. Très très familier, vulgaire. À ne pas utiliser n'importe où/avec n'importe qui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Faire le bâtard* est une expression d'argot populaire qui peut signifier plusieurs choses en fonction du contexte, qui ont en commun le manque de respect ou le manquement à une conduite socialement acceptable :

> Ton mec il fait le bâtard, et toi à chaque fois tu le pardonnes, je comprends pas (= sous-entendu il te trompe)
>
> Vas-y fais pas le bâtard, file-moi un bout de sandwich, j'ai trop la dalle (= je suis ton ami, tu pourrais partager un peu)
>
> T'as pas envie de sortir avec elle d'accord, mais fais pas non plus le bâtard, tu peux lui dire bonjour (= ne manque pas aux règles de politesse de base)
>
> Il fait un peu le bâtard ton pote, à chaque fois qu'on l'invite il dit qu'il va venir et au dernier moment il trouve une excuse bidon (= comportement décevant)
>
> Je dis pas ça pour faire le bâtard mais franchement je la trouve pas très jolie (= je sais que ça ne se fait pas de dire ça)